# Retrieving records fulfilling a condition using GROUP BY 

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, aggregate, having

I'd like to only select the rows where the count is greater than 1 (in other words the duplicates) right now from a few thousand records I am mostly seeing 1s with a few 2s and 3s here and there

```
SELECT count( * ) AS `Number` , GI . *
FROM `GeneralInformation` AS GI
GROUP BY `FirstName` , `Surname`
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT count( * ) AS `Number` , GI . *
FROM `GeneralInformation` AS GI
GROUP BY `FirstName` , `Surname` 
HAVING count(*)>1
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the Having clause

```
SELECT count( * ) AS `Number` , GI . *
FROM `GeneralInformation` AS GI
GROUP BY `FirstName` , `Surname` 
HAVING count( * ) > 1
```