# Counting each username in a table

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MYSQL COUNT GROUP BY question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997307/mysql-count-group-by-question)

[image]

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM product_id_1";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while( $record = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){

$array[] = $record['username'];

$unique_array = array_unique($array);

}


foreach( $unique_array as $list ){
    echo $list.'<br/>';
}
```

Greeting,

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to apply array_count_unique(). Reason is I need to find out the count of each individual user in the table, i.e how many times adam appears and how many times abcd appears.

---

UPDATE

This is what I've done according to you guys's suggestion:

```
$query = 'SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS username_count FROM product_id_1 GROUP BY username';

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($record = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {

    echo $record->username;

    echo $record->username_count;
}
```

Comment: You could get that directly from your query

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Highly wasteful code. you don't need to 'unique' your array on every iteration of the loop. A single unique call after you've fetched your db would be more efficient. And even more efficient would be to do the counting in the database itself, so you're not fetching and throwing away all kinds of data you don't need.

Comment: @PeeHaa Not the same, I'll look into the mysql thingy, but not today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly why we have RDBMS and SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS username_count, username
FROM
    product_id_1
GROUP BY
    username
```

Comment: This is what I've done as suggested:

Comment: I've changed my codes, thanks. Question, why pass in 1 into the COUNT()?

Comment: Convention.  You can use `COUNT(*)` if it makes you feel better - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1